# Why do I get Kinesis Exception after it works for a while

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I have written a Java Program using KCL which connects to Kinesis and downloads data from stream. But after sometime reading data successfully I start getting this exception. Need help from community to understand the reason behind this exception.

```
    7106292 [pool-2-thread-4] INFO  com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient - Unable to execute HTTP request: kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 failed to respond
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:143) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:837) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1760) [aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:790) [aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.10.61.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy.get(KinesisProxy.java:149) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.MetricsCollectingKinesisProxyDecorator.get(MetricsCollectingKinesisProxyDecorator.java:73) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.KinesisDataFetcher.getRecords(KinesisDataFetcher.java:67) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.getRecordsResultAndRecordMillisBehindLatest(ProcessTask.java:284) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.getRecordsResult(ProcessTask.java:249) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.call(ProcessTask.java:120) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:24) [amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.2.jar!/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
```

Comment: You have a problem with your client credential code. You are not using the right way of establishing credentials and refreshing them every hour. Consider using Lambda or using IAM Roles correctly.

Comment: You probably have not realized that I have written it works for a while and then it starts giving exception

Comment: I don't know how did you establish the first credentials for your connection, but if you are using temporary credentials, they stop working after a few minutes and you need to renew them. If you can give a better description of your code, it might help.